Does integrated Windows authentication in Ansible require a physical connection to MSSQL server?
Description:
I'm currently setting up an Ansible playbook to connect to an MSSQL database server hosted on Windows using integrated Windows authentication. However, I'm uncertain about the requirement for a physical connection from the Ansible host (Linux machine) to the MSSQL server. Here are the specifics and questions:
Environment Details:
Ansible is running on a Linux machine (specifically, RHEL).
MSSQL database server is hosted on a Windows machine within the same network/domain.
I have credentials for an Active Directory (AD) account that has appropriate access to the MSSQL database.
Authentication Method:
I intend to use integrated Windows authentication (auth: integrated) in my Ansible playbook to avoid storing plain-text credentials.
Concerns:
Physical Connection Requirement: Does integrated Windows authentication through Ansible require a physical network connection from the Linux host to the MSSQL database server? Due to security policies, direct physical connections from the Linux host to the database server are restricted.
Questions:
Does Ansible's use of integrated Windows authentication (auth: integrated) require a direct physical network connection from the Linux host to the MSSQL server?
If so, are there alternative authentication methods or configurations that can be used without requiring a physical connection?

The "physicality" of the connection has nothing to do with Windows Authentication. The device you are using to connect from must be in the same domain (or a trusted domain) that the SQL Server is in, and the application/user must be running/authenticated as a user within that domain and have access to said SQL Server.

And the client must be able to connect over TCP/IP to port 1433 (by default) on the SQL Server.  Not sure what you mean by a "physical connection".


I intend to use integrated Windows authentication (auth: integrated) in my Ansible playbook to avoid storing plain-text credentials.

It will not help you much with that, unless you're using smartcards with PKINIT. Otherwise the client still needs access either to the plain password, or to a password-equivalent keytab file.
There are ways to separate the Kerberos credential storage to a separate process running under a different Linux account (specifically: using gss-proxy), giving a similar result to Windows LSA, but it's still going to be plain-text on disk.

Does Ansible's use of integrated Windows authentication (auth: integrated) require a direct physical network connection from the Linux host to the MSSQL server?

No, it doesn't have any connection requirements beyond standard TCP/IP. It works by exchanging cryptographic proofs of credentials, not by relying on physical security.
The requirements that it does have are:

You must access the MSSQL server by its hostname or domain name (one that is registered wit AD), not by its IP address.

The client must be able to speak TCP/IP to the Active Directory domain controllers (specifically to the Kerberos service on port 88) and not just to the MSSQL server.


